# Ubuntu 64 bit Machinarium: error while loading shared libraries: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0

Tags: 64-bit, games, libraries, multiarch

I just downloaded Ubuntu 13.10 final beta 64 bit and every program that I use work flawlessly with the exception of "Machinarium" a very cool flash game. The game doesn't have a .deb package and I used to be able to play it before. I tried installing lib32 and ia32 and it says it is installed to the last version or if I try lib32-dev it says that is no longer available. Here is my ldd command result:

```
fz@Unknown:~/Games/Machinarium$ ldd Machinarium
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xf77c8000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0xf76c0000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0xf76a5000)
    libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0xf756f000)
    libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0xf755c000)
    libXt.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXt.so.6 (0xf7500000)
    libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0xf7461000)
    libfontconfig.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1 (0xf7427000)
    libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 => not found
    libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0 => not found
    libatk-1.0.so.0 => not found
    libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 => not found
    libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 => not found
    libpango-1.0.so.0 => not found
    libcairo.so.2 => not found
    libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0xf73d3000)
    libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 (0xf73ce000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0xf73c9000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0xf72c4000)
    libnss3.so => not found
    libsmime3.so => not found
    libssl3.so => not found
    libplds4.so => not found
    libplc4.so => not found
    libnspr4.so => not found
    libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0xf7280000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xf7263000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xf70b0000)
    libXrender.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1 (0xf70a4000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf77c9000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0xf7083000)
    libSM.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libSM.so.6 (0xf707a000)
    libICE.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libICE.so.6 (0xf7060000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0xf7046000)
    libexpat.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0xf701c000)
    libffi.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6 (0xf7015000)
    libpcre.so.3 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0xf6fd4000)
    libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0xf6fd0000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0xf6fc9000)
    libuuid.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 (0xf6fc2000)
```

Comment: Please edit your question and state what happens when you try to run the game. Please post the full error-message if there is one.

Comment: fz@Unknown:~/Games/Machinarium$ '/home/fz/Games/Machinarium/Machinarium' 
/home/fz/Games/Machinarium/Machinarium: error while loading shared libraries: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: You should just be able to do `sudo apt-get install packagename:i386` for the missing libraries to get 32-bit versions (AFAIK) (although that doesn't guarantee that appropriate library versions are still available).

Comment: Package ia32-libs:i386 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0

Comment: The system tells me that I have the libs installed, yet I can't find them.

Comment: "Ubuntu 13.10 final beta 64 bit", have you tried with an stable?

Comment: @Fonz Yes, the installer shows those packages. I've installed but still didnt load the shared library.

Answer (score 72):

apparently you have to install the libgtk2.0-0:i386 package.

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0:i386
```

Comment: That's not the only needed package. @Nothor listed all the needed packages and the game worked for me. `sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0:i386 libnss3:i386 libcurl3-gnutls:i386 libidn11:i386 libpango1.0-0:i386 libpangox-1.0-0:i386 libpangoxft-1.0-0:i386 librtmp0:i386 libxft2:i386
`

Comment: @MinaMichael those other libs will be automatically added to the install list by  the dependancy mechanim.

Comment: Update. The game's not working on 18.04. The package `librtmp0:i386` cannot be installed. The game gives this error: `error while loading shared libraries: libXt.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: @MinaMichael, `sudo apt install libxt6:i386` resolves issue on Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 10):

There are 2 options to run **Machinarium** on **Ubuntu 13.10 64bits**.

### Deb Package

If we have the .deb package (and yes! it is a **32bit package**).

You must to install it with Ubuntu Software Center (**not** using dpkg -i), so simply double click the file.

To remove the game

```
sudo dpkg -r machinarium
```

### TAR.GZ version

If you have the tar.gz version.

You need to install all those libraries.

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0:i386 libnss3:i386 libcurl3-gnutls:i386 libidn11:i386 libpango1.0-0:i386 libpangox-1.0-0:i386 libpangoxft-1.0-0:i386 librtmp0:i386 libxft2:i386
```

### Run it on STEAM

In both cases if you want to run it with STEAM as a NO Steam game, you must to install also this last library.

```
sudo apt-get install libxtst6:i386
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem here. This is not exactly a solution, but I'll try to add some information.

I tried @AdamOutler solution but after installing `libgtk2.0-0:i386` another dependencies were need which I solved installing `libnss3:i386` and `gtk2-engines-murrine:i386`. The problem was when the next step required a package called `unity-gtk2-module:i386` that depends on `unity-gtk-module-common:i386` which doesn't exists anymore.

I abandoned this approach and found that I could install the game directly from the Software Center (as I bought it from Humble Bundle). It worked like a charm! The crazy part is that there's no apparent difference between installations (.TGZ vs .DEB) - files inside folder looks to be the same (used `file` and `md5sum` commands to check).

Here is the list of dependencies from the installed package: `libatk1.0-0 (>= 1.12.4), libc6 (>= 2.4), libcairo2 (>= 1.2.4), libfontconfig1 (>= 2.8.0), libfreetype6 (>= 2.2.1), libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1), libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 (>= 2.22.0), libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.12.0), libgtk2.0-0 (>= 2.24.0), libnspr4 (>= 1.8.0.10), libnss3 (>= 3.12.0~1.9b1), libpango1.0-0 (>= 1.14.0), libstdc++6 (>= 4.1.1), libx11-6, libxext6, libxrender1, libxt6, libcurl3-gnutls`

One last thing is that I'd suggest to try to create a launcher for the game because I still have no success starting the game from bash.