# How to install library files

Tags: 14.04, shared-library, translation

I installed skype translting software CLOWN FISH in linux(ubuntu 14.04 LTS). But it was not working properly. In the clown fish website they have specified required library files for the proper working of the software. The following are the files. How do I install those files

> libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0
>   libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0
>   libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0
>   libfontconfig.so.1
>   libXrender.so.1
>   libX11.so.6
>   libgobject-2.0.so.0
>   libXft.so.2
>   libfreetype.so.6 
>   libpthread.so.0
>   librt.so.1
>   libz.so.1
>   libpng12.so.0
>   libstdc++.so.6
>   libm.so.6
>   libgcc_s.so.1
>   libc.so.6

Comment: What is your OS?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/356605/ubuntu-13-10-64-bit-machinarium-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libgtk-x1 ( http://packages.ubuntu.com/nl/trusty/libgtk2.0-0 probably holds all the files you mention)

Comment: there is no error message showing up while opening ClownFish. But the translation is not happening. In the site its said that "if yu have any problem with working , check the library files and and install missing ones" . So I checked the root/user/lib folder. All required lib files are not there. This is the site link    
http://clownfish-translator.com/linux.html

Comment: Take another look to `/usr/lib' (not /user/): is there a `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1` and/or `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1` for example? But anyway, try the hint of @Rinzwind, looks good.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Visit [**packages.ubuntu.com**](http://packages.ubuntu.com)

In its **Search the contents of packages** section, search for the file.

It will list the packages that contain particular file.

---

In your case, these packages are provided by the following packages:

```
libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0     libgtk2.0-0
libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0     libgtk2.0-0
libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0  libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0
libfontconfig.so.1      libfontconfig1 
libXrender.so.1         libxrender1
libX11.so.6             libx11-6
libgobject-2.0.so.0     libglib2.0-0 
libXft.so.2             libxft2
libfreetype.so.6        libfreetype6
libpthread.so.0         libc6
librt.so.1              libc6
libz.so.1               zlib1g
libpng12.so.0           libpng12-0
libstdc++.so.6          libstdc++6-4.8-dbg-arm64-cross
libm.so.6               libc6
libgcc_s.so.1           libgcc1 
libc.so.6               libc6
```

So you can install them by:

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libfontconfig1 libxrender1 libx11-6 libglib2.0-0  libxft2 libfreetype6 libc6 zlib1g libpng12-0 libstdc++6-4.8-dbg-arm64-cross libgcc1
```

---

Comment: I think only `libgtk2.0-0` was missing, and all other packages are dependencies of it, most or all already installed.